# How to create an AWS Amplify web app and consume REST Lambda API

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I am new to **AWS Amplify development**. I have **already developed Lambda Endpoint** which I have to integrate with in the Amplify Web form. Anyone can you suggest me the best approach to do this?